# the index of inertia with solution space

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}(m\le n)$ with $rank(A)=m$, let $Z$ be the matrix whose row number is $n$ and the column vectors are any basis of solution space of $A$.

Let $G\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be postive-definite.

Prove that the positive/negative index of inertia of 
$
\left( 
\begin{matrix}
   G & A^T \\
   A & 0 
\end{matrix}
\right)
 = 
$
the positive/negative index of inertia of $Z^TGZ + m$.

Comment: $A$ is not an equation. What do you mean by the "solution space of $A$"?

Comment: The solution space of $A$ means the set of $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$ which satisfies $A x=0$.

Comment: Are you sure you have written down the problem statement correctly? As it stands, it isn't true. Consider e.g. $A=0$ and $Z=I_n$. The positive index of inertia of $\pmatrix{G&A^T\\ A&0}=\pmatrix{G&0\\ 0&0}$ is $n$, but the sum of the positive index of inertia of $Z^TGZ$ and $m$ is $n+m$.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you for thinking, and I am checking the problem.

Comment: @user1551 Checked it. The rank of $A$ is $m$, and it needs to prove the negative index of inertia in addition.